# 1&1 hosting + azure cname + google apps mx

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, google, azure, application

I have a problem while hosting my website on azure :
I need to have an url mydomain.com, when deploying in azure it gives the url mydomain.cloudapp.net, so I do a cname record from mydomain.com to map with mydomain.cloudapp.net. 
But I also have set up mx records for mydomain.com to google mail servers in order to have emails like myname@mydomain.com, and the cname record drops these mx records... Then I try to do the following :
 1) keep mx records for mydomain.com and give up with the cname record here
 2) create a subdomain www.mydomain.com and do a cname to map this subdomain to mydomain.cloudapp.net
 3) do a redirect from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com
then I could keep my pretty mails and have a pretty url for my azure website.
BUT it seems to not work with 1&1 hosting, I can't map www subdomain to a cname.
Does anyone know if there is a workaround, or if I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you cannot have a CNAME record for a domain that has other record types.  It's for this reason that you should never have a CNAME record for your root domain (mydomain.com).

It seems like you have the right answers:

- Keep the MX record for mydomain.com pointed at Google.
- CNAME alias your www record to mydomain.cloudapp.net.
- Create a redirect from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com (via `.htaccess` rewrite-rule, or a basic HTML redirect page hosted on mydomain.com).

Comment: I've done this but it seems to not work all the time : it was working yesterday evening, but this morning when I go to www.mydomain.com or mydomain.com, the browser shows a dns error...<br/> but mydomain.cloudapp.net is reached, so it seems to be a pb with the dns mapping. may be sometimes one record overwrite the second one ? it is very weird

Comment: more precisely, I have a 105 error sometimes

Comment: That sounds like you either have a problem with your local DNS servers, or the DNS server that is authoritative for your domain.